# Jenkins Build Failures - But No Errors?

Tags: git, jenkins, robocopy

I have a Jenkins build which takes a pure HTML project from my Visual Studio Online Git SC. All it does it get the changes and use Robocopy to copy the files to the IIS Folder.

For some reason, every other build seems to end up marked as "Failed". Even though the Files are copied successfully to IIS and no errors are reported except "Finished: Failure".

If I run it again immediately, it does the same thing, except is successful.

How can I determine why successful builds are logged as failed?

```
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Screenshot: 
    https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gyo81afp5jozpx/Jenkins.PNG?dl=0

This is the content of the batch file

```
@ECHO Deploying Changes to Environment

robocopy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Personal Website - Dev\workspace\Source" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Personal Website\DEV" /MIR 

@ECHO Deployment Completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build fails because the executed batch file returns the value 1 (with the command `exit 1`). It is difficult to tell more information without the content of the batch, but it gives you a hint to investigate this issue. Are you sure you dont have an `exit 1` somewhere in your job's batch ?

To ensure a job end state is Success, the whole script must returns 0.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with the batch file contents. Will look at returning a value. Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

Consider using a slightly more verbose build system like MSBUILD, especially if using Visual Studio.  MSBuild will allow you to get more detailed information.

Consider setting state variables all over the place and then echoing them out at the end of the batch.

set Progress1= "hey, I got to this part of the build with out errors."
set Progress1Dest = "c:\foo\bar\file_that_got_copied"

With out a more verbose build script it will not be possible to troubleshoot these difficult errors.